# I wrote an article in Lyx but publishing journal wants it in TeX - Which steps do I take now?

Tags: lyx, conversion

I have written an article in LyX but have been requested to submit in the journals format (detailed TeX package is here) following their instructions from: 
http://cacm.acm.org/about-communications/author-center/author-guidelines/research-highlights-template/

Is it possible that you can give me the KISS edition of what to do with the package?

Comment: I removed the LyX version number from your title, since this may be a good generic question leading towards document type conversion.

Comment: Lyx can export a LaTeX file. I didn't look too closely, it looks like it wouldn't take much work to convert a paper to their format by hand. Is that not an option?

Comment: @Scribblemacher - thanks. Though I'm thinking about copy-pasting from the one to the other template, the method seems a bit _analogue_ in this _digital_ world. There must be a LyXteX solution...

Comment: [this page](http://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/CreatingLayouts) may be helpful. I don't use LyX at all, but from what I understand, layouts is how you alter the documentclass in LyX.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Read the documentation, specifically the User's Guide and Additional Features (accessible under the help menu).
If you want to try a quick way of doing it, see here:
http://www.briandalessandro.com/blog/how-to-use-a-new-latex-class-in-lyx/

Comment: Thanks for the link to the blog for starters. Why would I want to install MikTex? What's the purpose hereof?

Comment: @BHM I think that's just because that's how the large majority of Windows users install LaTeX. I use Ubuntu so I don't know much about Windows-specific solutions.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu too. What's your way around this?

Comment: To get the cls recognized by LaTeX, just put it somewhere texhash can find it. To do this, you could run the command `locate *cls` to see where most of your cls files are located. Then just stick it in with them. And then run `texhash`. Then to get LyX to recognize it, go to Tools > Reconfigure.

Comment: I would recommend sending an email to lyx-users@lists.lyx.org There is a lot more support for LyX there than on stackexchange. To see info on the mailing lists, see here http://www.lyx.org/MailingLists